# Cant send mail: Yandex email "Invalid contact address"

Tags: email

I've been trying to send mail on my Yandex email and I keep getting "Invalid contact address" error message. I've tried numerous emails and tried googling support but I cant find any anwsers.

Does anyone know any solutions?

Pic of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIxU.jpg

I've tried in Chrome, Firefox, internet explorer and a VPS running Linux.

Comment: Never encountered this problem. Yandex has an option to check for receiver's public key, and encrypt your message with it (secure only, or something like that). Not sure where exactly, but it could be the source of this error.

Comment: nor can my gmail send anything to my yandex... the problem goes both ways.

Answer (score 3):

You have to go to //Account Settings// in your top right menu. In the right panel it would say that "Your account is insufficiently secure". Which basically means that you haven't yet completed all steps to verify that you're not a spammer.

You can link your mobile phone number (via SMS code) and this will complete your registration and validation that you're not a robot. Then your mail account will be able to send and receive messages.

More details here https://www.reddit.com/r/Yandex/comments/6l6rkr/invalid_contact_address_error/

Comment: That's right. Same here. In my case, I tried to use Yandex to  escape from Google, but if Yandex needs my phone number to allow me to use it's mail service I'm afraid my relationship with Yandex is over only 5 minutes after it started. Good bye Yandex!

Comment: @AlbertoMartín you can buy a prepaid SIM card for $5, use it once to register the account and throw it out.

Comment: No, you can't throw it out since Yandex will use it some time in the future to check it's you the one using the account, while it could be done just with a secondary account for example. It's not just Yandex, also Yahoo, Xiaomi, etc. Many companies want as many information from you as possible, but to me, all of them are banned; I'm not accepting that abuse.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem as the responses in the reddit link demonstrate. I'm afraid Yandex is a very poor service. Even if it believes there is a security issue with your account, it should tell you so it is clear that you know that.